# I'm getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" error in axios patch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I am trying to update an array of objects using an Axios/Node.js API.  I have successfully created the array, but when I try to pass in through an axios patch request, I am getting the "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".  Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

My axios function is below:

```
export const updateTrans = async (transArr) => {
try {      
const res = await axios({
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: `http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/v1/property/${id}`,
  data: { 
      "transactions": transArr  }
});
  
if (res.data.status === 'success') {
  showAlert('success', 'Data updated successfully!');

}
 } catch (err) {
console.log(err.response.data.message );

showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
}
};
```

I have tried to stringify "transArr" as well, but still no luck.

Comment: Does the error occur on the line `console.log(err.response.data.message)`?

Comment: I believe it does, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're accessing `err.response.data` without checking if `err.response` exists. `err.response` is only present [if the request was made and there was a response](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors). If, for example, a CORS error or some network error occurred (or some other error inside the try block), it will not be present.

Just check that `err.response` exists before using it.

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err, err.response && err.response.data);

  if (err.response && err.response.data) {
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
    // that falls out of the range of 2xx
    showAlert("error", err.response.data.message);
    return;
  }

  showAlert("error", err.message);
}
```